# Under which condition "CALL" opcode does not increase the depth?

Tags: evm, geth-debugging, opcode, transaction-trace

I'm currently researching EVM opcode trace data(data fetched from "debug_traceTransaction"), and I meet several cases where the opcode "CALL" does not increase the depth.

I already know if the addr is something like "0x4", it's called precompiled identity contract, and the depth should not be increased.

However, there is still one case where everything seems fine but "CALL" does not increase the depth. It looks like:

CALL, gas = 0, addr = 0x...., value = 0x4563918244f40000, argsOffset = 0xf30, argsLength = 0x0

I wonder why it happens.

Comment: Is the target of the call a contract or an EOA?

Comment: It's an EOA address.

Comment: Oh. I understand a little bit now. Is that a simple Ether transfer?
But if so, how could EVM knows it's an EOA without using opcode like  
EXTCODESIZE?

Comment: You could look at the CALL source code. It checks if the target is a contract without using opcodes. The EVM has access to the world state and it doesn't need to execute an opcode.